# 12.04 - memory not fully recognized

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, memory

This might look like an easy one "get yourself different memory chips", but I'm not convinced:

I set up 12.04 64bit on a **new board with 8 GB** of memory plugged in. **I can see all 8 GB** in the BIOS (it says: 4 x 2GB plugged in), even though the self memory tests (run before I enter the BIOS) shows only 3820 MB.

If I launch Ubuntu, **system info also displays 3820MB**, but if I run the memory test (-> System Testing), it fails with

> Meminfo total: 3533740 kB DMI total: 8192000 kB Accuracy: 43.00 Memory
>   totals not close enough

Ooops, there are my 8GB !?

So, I'm desperately looking for any leads from here....

ps: double checked that I installed the 64bit version...

Comment: Bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/994103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment due to being new so I'm leaving this here.

If the POST (power on self-test) is showing 4 GB, that's a hardware or firmware issue. Have you double checked the modules are correctly seated? I don't know how to get Ubuntu to pick up the memory - but if it were my system I would be looking at the hardware.

Comment: I don't think you needed to comment - this is an answer (and likely the correct one).

Comment: after some playing around in the BIOS I got the memory fully recognized. thanks for answering!